# A basic confusion over uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose $F$ defined on $[a,b]$ is continuous. Is this true that

$$ \sup_{0 < h < \frac{1}{n}} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h} \leq \sup_{h \in \text{rationals between 0 and 1/n}} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}{h} + \epsilon$$

for any $\epsilon$. How to prove it ?

Comment: Are you assuming that $F$ is uniformly continuous? The title suggests so but the body does not.

Comment: Are you mixing up questions?  What does uniform continuity have to do with the rest of your question?  Is $x \in [a,b]$?

Comment: @AlexBecker: $F$ is defined on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : $F$ is defined on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Ah right, continuous on $[a,b] \implies $ uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

**Hint:** for any real, non-zero (possibly irrational) $h$, we can find a non-zero sequence of rationals $h_n \to h$, so that
$$
\frac{F(x + h) - F(x)}{h} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{F(x + h_n) - F(x)}{h_n}
$$